# adding new device for aosp

Tags: android, python, android-source

hello when i try to build my own new device in aosp i get the following error :

```
[ 82% 16519/19958] Target system fs image: out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system.img
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(true) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/ out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates && rm -rf out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system_image_info.txt) && (echo \"extfs_sparse_flag=-s\" >>  out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system_image_info.txt) && (echo \"selinux_fc=out/target/product/antonino/root/file_contexts.bin\" >>  out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system_image_info.txt) && (echo \"skip_fsck=true\" >>  out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system_image_info.txt) && (PATH=\$PATH ./build/tools/releasetools/build_image.py out/target/product/antonino/system out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system_image_info.txt out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system.img out/target/product/antonino/system || ( echo \"Out of space? the tree size of out/target/product/antonino/system is (MB): \" 1>&2 ; du -sm out/target/product/antonino/system 1>&2; if [ \"\" == \"ext4\" ]; then maxsize=; if [ \"\" == \"true\" ]; then maxsize=\$((maxsize - 4096 * 4096)); fi; echo \"The max is \$(( maxsize / 1048576 )) MB.\" 1>&2 ; else echo \"The max is \$((  / 1048576 )) MB.\" 1>&2 ; fi; mkdir -p out/dist; cp out/target/product/antonino/installed-files.txt out/dist/installed-files-rescued.txt; exit 1 ))"
Running:  mkyaffs2image -f out/target/product/antonino/system out/target/product/antonino/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system.img out/target/product/antonino/root/file_contexts.bin system
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/build_image.py", line 517, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/build_image.py", line 510, in main
    if not BuildImage(in_dir, image_properties, out_file, target_out):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/build_image.py", line 326, in BuildImage
    (_, exit_code) = RunCommand(build_command)
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/build_image.py", line 46, in RunCommand
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Out of space? the tree size of out/target/product/antonino/system is (MB): 
337 out/target/product/antonino/system
/bin/bash: / 1048576 : errore di sintassi: atteso un operando (il token dell'errore è "/ 1048576 ")
[ 82% 16519/19958] host C: libbz <= external/bzip2/decompress.c
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja.intermediate] Errore 1
```

these are my make file located at /device/vendor/mydevice

**AndroidProducts.mk**

```
PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := $(LOCAL_DIR)/full_antonino.mk
```

**BoardConfig.mk**

```
-include vendor/vendorname/antonino/BoardConfigVendor.mk

TARGET_ARCH := arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT := armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_ABI := armeabi-v7a
TARGET_CPU_ABI2 := armeabi
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT := generic
```

**device.mk**

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL),)
LOCAL_KERNEL := device/uniroma2/antonino-kernel/kernel
else
LOCAL_KERNEL := $(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL)
endif

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := \
    $(LOCAL_KERNEL):kernel

$(call inherit-product-if-exists, vendor/vendorname/antonino/device-vendor.mk)
```

**full_antonino.mk**

```
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/full_base.mk)
$(call inherit-product, device/vendorname/antonino/device.mk)

PRODUCT_NAME := full_antonino
PRODUCT_DEVICE := antonino
PRODUCT_BRAND := Android
PRODUCT_MODEL := antonino
PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER := vendorname
```

**vendorsetup.sh**

```
add_lunch_combo full_antonino-userdebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the build system ran out of space on the hard drive to write the final images.  Free up a bunch of disk space and try again.

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Out of space? the tree size of out/target/product/antonino/system is (MB): 337
```